# What does "Make my life easier" meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, idioms, expressions

"**Make my life easier**" and "**Make life easier**" are the same thing? Could I putting a *pronoun* or *determiner* between "**Make**" and "**Life**"?

Example: I wanna make **her** life easier.

Example: He want to make **my** life easier.

I need a definition for the expression too.

Comment: _Wanna_ is not correct English - it should be _I want to_ and _he wants to_.  _Make life easier_ just means life in general, not that of a particular person (though we can say _make life easier for her_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between "my life" and just "life" is that the former refers specifically to the life of the speaker. Without a determiner, "life" just refers to life in general or the lives of everybody.

For example:

> Having a car makes my life easier.

This means that a car makes things easier for *you*.

> Having a car makes life easier.

This is a more sweeping statement that suggests a car makes life easier for *anybody* who owns one.

Yes, you can use any possessive determiner such as *her, his, their* etc to refer to the lives of specific people, or groups of people.

Comment: Thank you so much! You help me a lot!